# making pvalue and fold change caculation more efficient

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      a     a     a     b     b     b
______________________________________
0     1     2     2     1     1     1
1     2     4     2     1     2     5
2     3     6     2     3     2     2
3     4     8     2     1     2     2
4     5    10     2     3     5     5
5     6    12     2     1     2     2
.     .     .     .     .     .     .     
.     .     .     .     .     .     .          
.     .     .     .     .     .     .     
8000  1    5      5     5     5     5
```

It comes with 6 columns (a and b represent 3 replicates each, thus they have the same name) and 8001 rows. I want to calculate the pvalue, fold change and the fdr adjusted pvalue for each row across column a and b. The coe for that looks like this:

```
pvalues = pd.DataFrame()
fcvalues = pd.DataFrame()
qvalues = pd.DataFrame()


pvalue = [stats.ttest_ind(a = data['a'].iloc[i],b = data['b'].iloc[i])[1] for i in np.arange(data.shape[0])]

pvalues['a vs b'] = -np.log10(pvalue)

fold_change_values['a vs b'] = [np.mean((np.array(data['a'].iloc[i]) - np.array(data['b'].iloc[i])))
                                for i in np.arange(int_data.shape[0])]

qvalues['a vs b'] = fdrcorrection(pvalue)
```

the problem in this code is that it takes 21 sec to execute. Do you guys have any suggestion how to make this faster and more efficient? I'm new to coding so don't have a lot of experience making code more efficient. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can vectorise it like this:

```
pvalues = pd.DataFrame()
fcvalues = pd.DataFrame()
qvalues = pd.DataFrame()

a_data = data['a'].to_numpy()
b_data = data['b'].to_numpy()

# T test for each row pair.
pvalue = stats.ttest_ind(a=a_data, b=b_data, axis=1)[1]

pvalues['a vs b'] = -np.log10(pvalue)

fold_change_values = pd.DataFrame()
# Mean difference for each row.
fold_change_values['a vs b'] = np.mean(a_data - b_data, axis=1)

qvalues['a vs b'] = fdrcorrection(pvalue)
```

This should be much faster as it eliminates the `.iloc` indexing and `for` loops in the list comprehension.